# Meaning of "previous in system / Context" Chrome DevTools

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, memory-leaks, devtools

I was inspecting the Memory Summary of a Heap Snapshot of my node.js application in Chrome DevTools and found a leaked object to be reachable via `previous in system / Context @266607`. Can anybody explain what that means, exactly? I understand what `context` means in this case, but for `previous`I could not find any documentation. To be clear, I mean this kind of graph:

[image: I am talking about this type of inspector]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I attached an image to clarify, but no code is relevant for this kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Context` object has a `previous` field, referencing (i.e. pointing to) another `Context` object, which is the previous context of the current one (If you're really interested, here's its [header file definition](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/0acdf36510e72d5dac5777d893e77716235b7c39/src/objects/contexts.h#411)).

As an example, the following is a screenshot I took of a `Context` object appearing in my own Summary view (I describe below how to get to this view):

[image]

In your image, the `Context` object with id `@831295` has its `previous` field referencing the `Context` object with id `@2801553`:

[image]

You can see it for yourself by navigating to the view I screenshot above, as follows:

- Right-click the `Context` object with id `@831295`.
- Select "Reveal in Summary view", and you'll be navigated to *that* `Context` object.
- You can then reveal its fields, and see that it has a field named `previous`, which is a `Context` itself, whose id is `@2801553`.